# How to change Remot Ip address from jsoup request?

Tags: java, web-services

I have Jsoup code and successfully send request.Also this code work fine in hide/change 'X-Forwarded-For' Header data, but i cant hide/change Remote/System Ip Address.
Client Side Code:

```
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX/microFin/XXXX")
               .header("X-Forwarded-For", "192.168.0.1").get();
```

Server Side Code:

```
 @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
       String authCredentials = request.getHeader("Authorization");
       String pathInfo = request.getServletPath();/////api/auth

       String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
       String ip11 = request.getRemoteAddr();
       if (ip == null) {
           ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
       }
       System.out.println("IP-ADDRESS::" + ip);//192.168.0.1
       System.out.println("IP-ADDRESS::" + ip11);//actual ip ???
```

If any solution for change System Ip then please help me.

Comment: Hello, are you working with `bhaumik shah` and `Rajan Desai` ? You just posted the exact same question of these two people...

Comment: In order to change your remote/system ip address you need to use a service like proxy or vpn. As far as I know, this is not possible to change the IP address after a request has been made.

Comment: thank you for better direction. can you please suggest/refer any link/code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VPN service to hide the IP address of the client machine. There are several software ranging from premium to paid.

My software of preference is: [TunnelBear Link](https://www.tunnelbear.com/b/tunnelbear-tryfree/?aff_id=2940&offer_id=40&trans_id=102a8456b4efb0c4b4a1f6bf7f27c8&utm_source=Affiliate&utm_campaign=TBTF)

Comment: Thank you for good suggestion but i want dynamically change ip and this will handle by java code.

Comment: You can use a VPN service that allows an API which can be triggered/stopped by your code.